# HTML Validation - (found d) (expected f)

Tags: html

I have a small problem. I have check my source code for possible errors and it returned the following:

> Line 233, Column 3: required character
>   (found d) (expected f)

Line 233 is the following code:

```
    <div id="content">
    <div id="search_method">
    <div>
    <-- CONTENT 1-->
    </div>
    <div>
   <-- CONTENT 2-->
    </div>  <-- Line 233 -->
    </div>
    </div>
```

The extra `<div>` are there because they are part of my Tabs scripts (see jQuery Tools Tabs).

I cant figure out why there should be an "f" instead of "d" (for **d**iv)....

Comment: In JS it does not point you exactly to the correct line/character with respect to you screen/file, try to review the last line of your javascript code that might be executing above these lines.

Comment: thanks for the info! I will coonsider the fact and look through my code again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are validating your code against XHTML5 on [validator.nu](https://validator.nu/). Try validating it again HTML5.

XHTML5 has a bunch of strict requirements such as closing `meta` and `img` tags like `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` (note the `/`). Often if you get this error you have forgotten to close one of these tags.